# Checkboxes Defaulting to Selected When Not Desired

Tags: 7, forms

This is going to be sound like a real stupid question, but for the life of me I don't know how to fix it. I have inherited some code that I need to maintain, and the issue I am experiencing is that a form containing checkboxes is displayed, and they are always all selected. The code for the checkboxes is as follows:

```
$license_result = db_select('licenses')
  ->fields('licenses', array('code', 'name'))
  ->execute();

foreach ($license_result as $license) {
  $licenses[$license->code] = htmlspecialchars($license->name);
}
$selected_licenses = array();
return array(
  'selected_licenses' => array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#title' => t('Licenses to Display'),
    '#description' => t('Select which licenses the student should be able to select'),
    '#options' => $licenses,
    '#default_value' => $selected_licenses,
  ),
);
```

I though that by having an empty array for #default_value would deselect all checkboxes. Am I reading the form API wrong in this regard? Eventually I would like to set the default values but right now I want to make sure they start off as unselected.

Thanks.

Comment: You're not using the [Multistep module](http://drupal.org/project/multistep) by any chance, are you? There's a [known bug](http://drupal.org/node/1419120) in that which affects checkboxes specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set the value in each checkbox, so probably this would be it :

```
foreach ($license_result as $license) {
  $licenses[$license->code] = htmlspecialchars($license->name);
  $licensevalues[$license->code] = 0;
}
$selected_licenses = array();
return array(
  'selected_licenses' => array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#title' => t('Licenses to Display'),
    '#description' => t('Select which licenses the student should be able to select'),
    '#options' => $licenses,
    '#default_value' => $licensevalues,
  ),
);
```

Comment: That was a good idea and I tried it but they still come out selected. I suspect that somewhere else in the code is modifying the selection but I can't seem to find where.

Comment: try to create a form_alter hook in which you would just `dpm($form)` so you could see whether something else is set there